# Hobocopy data copy windows 7

Tags: windows-7, copy

How can I use Hobocopy to copy data on Network? I am able to copy data on Local drive. But I want to copy that data on network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Hobocopy is capable of copying data *to* a network connection, via either a mapped network drive or a UNC path. However, it cannot copy data *from* a network destination, because it relies on Volume Shadow Snapshots, which are a local-only feature of Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the Information. Can you please tell me how can I use mapped network path in Hobocopy? I have already tried once, but its not working. May be the protocol i followed, was wrong.